# upgrade to iOS 11.3 broke __weak UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

yesterday I updated my iPhone 6s to iOS 11.3.  When I opened my application it immediately crashed.  I tracked down the crash to the following code where I found that my 'yes' UIAlertAction was nil.

Even after I took out the __weak declarations, the code runs and doesn't crash, however my alert doesn't pop up on screen as it used to.  I used several of these alerts all over the place.

Is there something wrong with my code or is this a legitimate 11.3 iOS bug?
Has anyone else had a similar crash after updating to 11.3?
This code has been working perfectly fine for 1.5 yrs now with no recent
changes.

```
- (void) alertGotoAppSettings:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)msg :(UIViewController *)view
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                    message:msg
                                                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction __weak *yes = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:LOC(@"Yes")
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             // Launch Settings for GPS
                             if (UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil) {
                                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
                                 if (IS_IOS_10_OR_LATER) {
                                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
                                      {
                                      }];
                                 }
                                 else {
                                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                                 }
                             }
                         }];

    UIAlertAction __weak *no = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:LOC(@"No")
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                             });
                         }];

    [alert addAction:no];
    [alert addAction:yes]; <---- 'yes' is nil here

    UIAlertController __weak *weakAlert = alert;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertController *strongAlert = weakAlert;
        [view presentViewController:strongAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Comment: why is it `__weak`? That is a bug in *your* code. The GC can instantly collect the instance since nothing is referencing it.

Comment: I thought a weak reference hung around until the end of the scope of the method.  If it can go away at any time, whats the purpose of it at all?  I mean if it can be deleted in the very next line then whats the point?

Comment: Because things beyond the scope might hold references and weak allows one to safely use something without incurring retain cycles or impacting lifecycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `yes` nor `no` should be `__weak`. Likewise, the `weakAlert`/`strongAlert` pattern should be excised from this code snippet.

Weak references should only be used when the object in question has other explicit strong references, but you simply don't want your code to establish yet another strong reference. In particular, you use `weak` when there is a risk of a strong reference cycle. But no such potential strong reference cycle exists here. Frankly, it simply doesn't make sense to use `weak` in conjunction with local variables where there aren't other explicit strong references involved.

Bottom line, `weak` means "this object can be deallocated and this particular reference can be set to `nil` when there are no strong references remaining". But in this case, since your only reference is that `weak` reference, there aren't any strong references. So and ARC is free to deallocate them.

The code in question may have worked in the past (perhaps ARC was being more conservative about when to release objects), but it is correct to remove these `weak` references in this case. They serve no purpose and make the scope of the objects ambiguous.